# AngularJS: Scope in multiple views not updating

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I have one controller and two views.

**ClustersContorller**

```
angular.module('app.controllers').controller('ClustersController', [
  '$scope', 'ClustersService', function($scope, ClustersService) {
    ClustersService.getAll().success(function(data) {
      $scope.clusters = data;
    });
    $scope.$on('cluster:added', function(event, data) {
      ClustersService.createNew(data).then(
        function(res) {
          $scope.clusters.push(res.data);
        },
        function(res) {
          console.log( 'Unable to create a cluster!' );
        }
      );
    });
  }
]);
```

Now one view is working great when I send the HTTP request and update the scope variable by pushing to `$scope.clusters`:

```
<section class="clusters">
    <h2 ng-show="clusters.length < 1">You have no clusters :(</h2>
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-ng-repeat="cluster in clusters" data-template="{{cluster.templateId}}">
    <h2> {{ cluster.name }} </h2>
    <p> {{ cluster.description }} </p>
  </a>
    <add-cluster-modal></add-cluster-modal>
</section>
```

But the other view that is bound with this controller does not update scope.clusters in the bindings:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-ng-controller="ClustersController">
  <li data-ng-repeat="cluster in clusters">
    <a> {{cluster.name}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Just to be clear the first view is bound by the `$routeProvider` and the second one is a part of a template included directly into the app main html file by `ng-include=" 'templates/partials/header.html' "`

Please feel free to ask me if something is confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular controllers are not singletons, and every time you use `ng-controller` in a view, you create a new instance of that controller (see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)). This is the reason why your second controller doesn't show the data - it's scope is not aware of the scopes of other instances.

You can either save the model's data under `$rootScope`, or create some eventing mechanism in your controller, that would inform other instances of data change.